# Streams with loop in another loop

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a code with loop in another loop and I want to use stream there but can't find any solution.

So here's my code

```
for (WebElement currency : elementList) {
            for (WebElement amount : amountList) {
                if (currency.getText()
                            .contains(currencyType) && amount.getText()
                                                             .contains(amountInCards)) {
                    return amount;
                }
            }
        }
throw new NoSuchElementException("No element found.");
```

and give me a clue or solution how to do this by stream, please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a nested loop here. This is how I would do it with streams:

```
if (elementList.stream().noneMatch(c-> c.getText().contains(currencyType))) {
    throw new NoSuchElementException("No element found.");
}

return amountList.stream()
          .filter(amount -> amount.getText().contains(amountInCards))
          .findFirst()
          .orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementException("No element found."));
```

Notice that `elementList` is entirely independent of what you return. It only throws an exception if you can't find the correct currency.

The `orElseThrow` method is a method on `Optional` that returns the value of the `Optional` if it exists, or throws an exception if it does not exist. The `findFirst` method on `Stream` returns an `Optional` containing the first element of the stream if it exists, or an empty `Optional` if the stream is empty.

Comment: I was going to down-vote you, but realized that the question code was really weird and that you unwrangled it correctly, so.... Well done.